# Collision Handling in a hash table

Tags: c++, hashtable

I am trying to create a hashtable to determine the index where a lexime (String) needs to be inserted. The hash function and table works fine but the problem I am facing is with the palindrome and the string with the same sets of characters. If there is a string in the table lets say "nab" and if the user enters another string "ban" then the new one replaces the one from the table.

here is a sample code that I am currently working with.

```
String lexime;
int token;  //This determines the index in the table
String hashTable[20];
cin >> lexime;
token=hash(lexime);
hashTable[token]=lexime;

int function hash(String lex){
    int token=0;
    int length=lex.size();
    for (int i=0;i<length;i++){
        char temp=lex[i];
        token+=(int)temp;
    }
    return token%20;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally each hash table entry is a linked list so your collisions are all in the list... the hash is to speed up the search to just the collision list.

Comment: So do I need to create a linked list and change the datatype of my array to linkedlist? If the token value match then just extend the linked list in the same array index?

Comment: correct.  your "insert" will calculate the hash index, check if the item already exists in the list at that index, if not add it.

Comment: Thanks it worked, now I can use STL functions once the list has been found in the array index to search for the correct lexime.

Answer (score 0):

The collisions are, as you said, the result of your hash function not taking order of characters into account. To resolve this, a simple way would to multiply `(int)temp` by `(i + 1)` so that the value of `temp` is affected by its position.

Also read up on [collision resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution).